# Terminate Application on exit in Windows CE 6.0

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm running `Windows CE 6.0` on an ARM processor device using `.NET CF 2.0 SP2` with an application written in `C#`.

I'm experiencing a problem where my application continues to run after it has closed. The application opens a connection with something connected to the device and doesn't release it until properly closed. Because of this, I cannot reopen and use the application while it continues to run and I can't run other applications which wish to use the attached device either.

I have tried to run `Application.Exit()` and all of my threads have the `IsBackground` property set to `true` but this doesn't work. After closing the application I can use a task manager and see that the process continues to run.

I'd normally use `Environment.Exit()` but this is not available in CF, unfortunately.

Is there any of methods I can try and use or causes that would be making this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Process thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
thisProcess.Kill();
```

And see what happens. It's obviously not ideal to closing a application, but it might work as a last resort, especially if you're handling the saving and discarding of data manually prior to that anyway.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of using this as a temp-fix, it does work too. As you said it isn't ideal but it will be good to use in the mean time til I figure out what is causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run your app inside the debugger? You may try to break it while it is in the "zombie" state to understand what is preventing it from terminating.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this:

I found the problem was that with Windows CE / WEHH / .NET Compact, applications don't exit on pressing the X button on a form, they are only minimized (meaning the closing event doesn't get called).

As per one of the answers on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f426dfb-f1b7-4745-aa32-d14107915585/application-doesnt-close-when-x-clicked?forum=netfxcompact) page, the close button can be changed to actually exit the application by setting the form property 'MinimizeBox' to false.

```
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

This will change the X button to an OK button, and will exit the application completely.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can Help. Set Thread's Background Property to *false* before calling **Application.exit()**;

```
private void BtnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread1.IsBackground = false;
  Thread2.IsBackground = false;

  Application.exit();
}
```